# Prevent Permission Monitor from resetting

Tags: notifications, permissions

The new Permission Monitor keeps resetting the exceptions that I give it.

Often, when I send or receive texts using Next SMS (previously Handcent), the Permission Monitor gives me a notification telling me that Next is using the "Send SMS" permission in the background.

Since this is my chosen SMS app, I'm obviously ok with it sending texts.

The problem is, even though I've told the Permission Monitor repeatedly to add Next to the whitelist, it keeps resetting my preferences and sporadically starts giving me warnings again about the permission usage.

It seems to reset every time Next is updated, but it seems ridiculous to reset the settings associated with an app every time it's updated, even when no new permissions are required.

Is there a way to stop the permission preferences from being reset constantly?

Note 8, Android 7.1.1

Comment: Sorry missed that :(